# How to Programmatically Buy SPL Solana Tokens Using Python and the Solana SDK?

Tags: solana-program, python, solana-py

I am exploring ways to automate the process of buying SPL Solana tokens using Python and the Solana SDK. I have been working with the Solana blockchain and understand the basics of creating wallets, sending transactions, and interacting with smart contracts.

However, I am specifically looking for guidance on programmatically buying SPL tokens. I would appreciate it if anyone could provide a step-by-step example or code snippet demonstrating how to initiate a purchase of SPL tokens using Python and the Solana SDK.

Executing the transaction and obtaining confirmation.
I've gone through the official Solana documentation, but a practical example or code snippet would be immensely helpful. Any insights, code samples, or recommended resources would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use [Jupiter’s swap API.](https://station.jup.ag/docs/apis/swap-api).

It helps you gather all the information you needed for a transaction.
You just have to sign and send it.

Comment: hey you idea worked well but can you help me with something i have an error that states  Error sending transaction: invalid transaction: Transaction loads an address table account that doesn't exist